# Inverse Chi Square Function in C#

Tags: c#, function, math, chi-squared, math.net

this is the equation of what I want to implement:

[image: chi]

I have already made the inside up to comma. But I have really no idea how to implement C^-1 with 2n degrees of freedom, is there any function in Math class?

Looking at the description on the wiki I am still confused like a lil kid.
[wikipedia inverse chi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-chi-squared_distribution)

I have found the Python implementation:
[Python implementation of chi function](http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/064/6467/6467s2.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the [ChiSquare distribution](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/ChiSquared.htm) provided by [math.net](http://www.mathdotnet.com/).

Comment: Should I use CDF, PDF or PDFln in my example?

Comment: An example would be nice, because ChiSquared(5) looks like it would be random, where 5 is number of freedom, which is 2n in my example.

Comment: I have used PDF, and it gives um, okeish results.. maybe it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, C^-1 == 1/C. Using Wolframs definition I see that C is actually a Gamma Function:  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseChiSquareDistribution.html
I would research what the Gamma Function is doing and go from there. As a note to [Thiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/537323/thiago-s%c3%a1) this is not the same as a Chi Square Distribution so you cannot use the function you offered.